# Replace XFce4 with Cinnamon without Log-In Screen

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments, cinnamon, chroot, chromebook

I have a Google I/O Chrome Pixel that I've been playing around with [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).

This is my first real shot at Ubuntu and have made the upgrade from 12.04 -> 13.04.  Using `chroot`, I can run both Chrome OS and Ubuntu side by side and toggle between the two using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Because of the `chroot`, I am not given a login manager meaning I cannot change the DE.  I have installed Cinnamon and would like to try it out as default.  I tried a `cinnamon --replace` which only killed both DEs.  Can anyone help with any other ideas?

EDIT1: I figured out what my problem was.  `cinnamon --replace` was failing because I did not have the necessary gnome-themes-* packages installed.

`sudo apt-get install cinnamon gnome-themes-* xserver-xorg` should get everything you need.

Now, how could I go about making this run from startup?  Right now if I end my chroot environment and restart it will still use Xfce.  I would like cinnamon to be default.

Answer (score 0):

If you log out of your account. You need to click on your account, in log in screen, then click on upper right corner of grey box and then click on cinnamon. If you try to log in you will be prompted. Just answer make it default.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just logout if you are using Crouton. So, a way to change the Desktop Environment from the command line or config files is necessary when using a Chromebook+Crouton+Ubuntu.